# how to access object property name in v-for

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm new to vuejs.
I started to play with v2.
I have a simple array with object in my instance data property:

```
items: [{"theProprtyName": "thePropertyValue"}]
```

I do simple v-for:

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-item v-for="item in items">
        <span v-for="(key, value) in map">
            {{key}}--{{value}}
        </span>
    </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

renders:

```
theProprtyName--thePropertyValue
```

Is there a more elegant way to create to achieve the end result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is mappings?

Comment: You can create a function that accepts the items array and returns an object that has known properties like 'key' and 'value' an then in the  v-for access them as 'item.key' and 'item.value'.

Comment: nice and simple but not vue-ish. not sure which one I prefer, thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can get the property name referencing the name, instead of the index, in the v-for:

```
<div v-for="(item, name) in items" :key="name"> {{name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward solution is to make use of `computed` properties:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [
      {
        foo: 'value1',
        bar: 'value2',
        baz: 'value3'
      },
      {
        foo: 'value4',
        bar: 'value5',
        baz: 'value6'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    objList() {
      return this.list.map((item) => Object.keys(item))
    },
    keyValuePair() {
      return this.list.map((item) => {
        return Object.keys(item).reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc.push(`${curr} - ${item[curr]}`)
          return acc
        }, [])
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h3>Loop as normal</h3>
    <div v-for="item in list">{{item}}</div>
  <div>
  <div>
    <h3>Loop as normal</h3>
    <div v-for="item in objList">{{item}}</div>
  <div>
  <div>
    <h3>Key-Value Pair</h3>
    <div v-for="(item, idx) in keyValuePair">
      <div>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```